# App performing continuous background activity - even during terminated state

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, battery, uibackgroundtask

I just noticed that my app's background activity is sky-rocketing after few mins of usage.

1. Location permission disabled.
2. App's background refresh disabled from the iOS Settings app.
3. Push notifications enabled.

It keeps on getting launched/running in the background, even after I have terminated the app from the Recently Used Apps window by swiping up.

Any leads on how to debug is very much appreciated.

I have shared the battery usage %.
Also, Xcode's Battery Usage stats from the Organizer-tool

**Battery Usage stats per version**

[image]

**Battery usage %**
[image]

Observations:

1. Background activity stops when the phone is restarted.
2. Background activity happens even when I have disabled Background App Refresh or in LowPowerMode

Comment: No clue. Just to be sure, do you have it connected to Xcode all the time?

Comment: @Honey, nope, that's AppStore downloaded build shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: This has been resolved. This was happening due to push notifications. With content-available enabled, the app gets launched in the background and it was going in a specific code flow that lead to an exception, due to which the app was not getting terminated. This idling of app in memory consumed battery for hours. Solving that exception helped kill this background app process.

Comment: but what did you do to allow the app continue running? I mean you said you don't have locaitonTracking enabled. So I wonder how the app was kept in memory?